# Honeywell CN80 not recognized by Windows

Tags: windows, usb, android, pnp

I have a Honeywell Dolphin CN80 device on loan for development purposes for our client. Problem is, Windows will not recognize it at all on my primary machine (Windows 10) work machine. However, the client's machine was able to recognize it when connected to the USB port.

I also have a personal development machine, also Windows 10, and that recognizes it, so I was able to do the development of the application on my personal machine but ultimately need to have it work on machines other than my own.

I know there could be many reasons such as lock-down security features in Windows, but I have tried this device with several other machines in our office including my supervisor's machine and personal machines and still to no avail being recognized by Windows. On another co-worker's machine, it only SOMETIMES gets recognized.

The only CONSTANT recognition of the device is on my personal Alienware machine. When the device connects, and I look at all the registry settings associated with Device Manager of the attached device, it is referencing all Apple context files/drivers -- for an Android based device. Makes no sense to me.

And as for first comment and drivers, I even tried going to the manufacturer and they don't have any such drivers.  It's just supposed to "work" with Windows and other generic existing Android-based drivers.

I really need some assistance on this one. Thanks

Comment: There might be a driver that needs installed.

Comment: @Moab, forgot to include, and edited answer to reflect, but tried that too.

Comment: Does it show up in device manager when connected? Did you try all the usb ports?

Comment: @Moab, no, not showing in device manager anywhere and yes on the different ports.

Comment: Try a different USB cable. Does Windows recognize anything when you plug-in the phone (e.g. the device connected sound, any change in device manager)? You could try to use an active USB hub in between the computer and the phone (in case it is a power issue).

Comment: Got the same problem...did you solve it? Where did you find updated drivers? Honeywell download site sucks!!!

Comment: @StefanoVuerich, sort-of, answered my own question for you to see.  Hope it works for you too.  Comment back if it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after a wide variety of research, I had a resolution that worked without a problem.  If someone can further clarify why, great, but this worked for me.

My son had a multi-port USB dongle.  I upgraded his to a new one with wired ethernet adapter included and took his.

I connected the multi-port USB to my machine and the scanner to the dongle USB port and it worked.  Disconnected and put directly into the port after removing the dongle, it failed.  Plugged back in the dongle, it worked connected to that.

So, my only thought is that it MIGHT be different settings from the dongle recognized ports, or powered ports, or whatever, but it worked.  No updated drivers or anything else.

Comment: I've got some strange behaviours as well. Basically I connected the USB docking station to another computer: the first time the connection went OK, but next attempts failed. I've also tried to connect the docking station through a multi-port adapter; same result: some attempts worked, many others does not work...

Comment: @StefanoVuerich, I agree with you on the problems with the device.  Its almost like there is some failed handshaking going on between the device to Windows.  Their support was lame at best, even when I had some high-up techs helping (via Gov't contract, they want to help), and it was still pulling teeth with no definitive answer.  As of now, I am thankful with my new machine that it does recognize it.  Good luck.  Another item was the version on the CN80 which I had to do an image upgrade to (which took several attempts too).